# Debugging Scala sequences in IDE?

Tags: scala

When I try to debug the following code in either IntelliJ or Scala IDE, the debugger gets stuck on the breakpoint of the first line and tries to step through all 100 iterations. IntelliJ's run to cursor doesn't skip over the line and eclipse doesn't either. Any ideas on how to handle this case?

```
object Test extends App {
  val data: Array[Int] = (0 to 100).map(i => (i+1)).toArray
  println(data)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, it looks like the breakpoint on the line with the map is at the apply of the anonfun, and trying to step in brings you back to the breakpoint, while stepping over leaves you at the specialized apply.

But you can also select a stack frame and set a breakpoint there, for instance at the `result` at the end of TraversableLike.map. You can disable the first breakpoint (in the breakpoints view) to get there quickly.

Then step-return and step-in gets you to the newArray.

You can use javap in the usual way to see what you stepped in:

```
javap -p -v bin/Test\$\$anonfun\$1.class
```